# How does DataReader (DbCommand) handle DB communication?

Tags: c#, datareader, dbconnection

In a software which I'm trying to understand, the DataReader class is received from a IDbCommand-type (inherited) via ExecuteReader().

I'm pretty new to C# and database communication, so: How does DataReader handle the communication with a database?

- Does it receive the entire response from the query when performing
  ExecuteReader(), and then the response is stepped through locally with reader.Read()?
- Or does each reader.Read() call get the next item from the database over the network?
- Or, something else which I've not thought of?

Comment: Consider using Microsoft Reference Source to look at the implementation detail: [DbDataReader class](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/Common/DbDataReader.cs,f7c2de36229de361) and [SqlDataReader class](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlDataReader.cs,d576786f0fd1b1dc).

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.commandbehavior(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Although it's up to the implementor of IDataReader to support streaming or not, most do it to improve performance. Sometimes you can even control how much data is buffered before requiring the next network access.

Comment: The DataReader is supposed to behave as a firehose, forward-only reader, returning rows as fast as the application can read them.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, "it depends", because `DbDataReader` is an abstract class that can be implemented any way you see fit -- including buffering the whole result.

Practically, though, the interface is geared towards piecemeal reading, and so are the implementations. If we take [`SqlDataReader`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlDataReader.cs) as the example, the initial call to `.ExecuteReader()` will start processing of the command and will cause the server to offer results, then each call to `.Read()` will fetch a row over the network. However, not every call to `.Read()` necessarily involves network traffic, as multiple rows might be bundled in a packet so the read can be satisfied from a buffer.

The same applies to columns, even -- they may span network packets or even contain streams, so all the `.GetX()` methods potentially involve an additional network roundtrip (which is why all of them also have `Async` versions in .NET 4.5 and higher).